# MSSQL: T-SQL to find only the IDs that are found in all 4 columns regardless of row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that lists all of the classes all of our students are taking. Along with the Students ID, there are 4 columns in the table that contain the IDs of our teachers assigned to a students class, the column names showing what position this teacher has for that student.

An example of the [Courses] table structure is:

```
|StudentsID|CourseChair|Member1|Member2|Member3|
------------------------------------------------
| 1234     |  12       |  44   |  38   |  99   |
| 2345     |  44       |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |
| 4566     |  38       |  88   |  72   |  31   |
| 4368     |  11       |  93   |  44   |  NULL |
| 9812     |  12       |  38   |  99   |  44   |
```

We have tens of thousands of students with hundreds of teachers, but I want to see a list of Teacher IDs only if that ID is present in all 4 columns, regardless of the row/record.  So in the above table, I would want to return *only* Teacher ID 44 since that ID is a CourseChair, and a Member1, Member2, and a Member3; what student or what class is unimportant in this situation.

I've tried this with `CTE`, multiple nested `SELECT` in the `SELECT` and/or in the `WHERE`, as well as 4 self-joins, none of which are very efficient with as many records I'm dealing with.  Can someone help me find the best way to write this query?  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What happens if you update member3 value to 38 in 4368 row?. Then what is your expected output?

Comment: After update, expected output would be 38 and 44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT StaffMember
FROM StudentClass
UNPIVOT (StaffMember FOR Position IN ([CourseChair], [Member1], [Member2], [Member3])) U
GROUP BY StaffMember
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Position) = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using intersect:

```
select CourseChair from #yourstudents where CourseChair is not null
intersect
select member1 from #yourstudents where Member1 is not null 
intersect
select member2 from #yourstudents where member2 is not null
intersect
select member3 from #yourstudents where member3 is not null
```

Comment: And add a where clause to ignore the null values!

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward.  Just JOIN (INNER) on each column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C0.CourseChair
FROM Courses C0
    INNER JOIN Courses C1
        ON C0.CourseChair = C1.Member1
    INNER JOIN Courses C2
        ON C1.Member1 = C2.Member2
    INNER JOIN Coureses C3
        ON C2.Member2 = C3.Member3
```

Here's another way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CourseChair
FROM Courses 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM Courses C1
       WHERE c1.Member1 = Courses.CourseChair) > 0
      AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM Courses C2
       WHERE c2.Member2 = Courses.CourseChair) > 0
      AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM Courses C3
       WHERE c3.Member2 = Courses.CourseChair) > 0
```

If, however, the issue is efficiency, you probably need to look at indexing.  If you have Database Engine Tuning Adviser, that can help.

**You would probably need an index on each column.  If you don't, then you're doing table searches for each of them, and that will, in fact, take forever.**

** UPDATE **

Here's another strategy that may improve the efficiency/speed:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (CourseChair) AS ID FROM Courses
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT (Member1) AS ID FROM Courses
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT (Member2) AS ID FROM Courses
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT (Member3) AS ID FROM Courses
) T1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

** And one final thought***

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CourseChair)
FROM Courses
WHERE CourseChair IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (Member1)
        FROM Courses
        WHERE Member1 IN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT (Member2)
            FROM Courses
            WHERE Member2 IN 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT (Member3)
                FROM Courses
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Something very similar was my first attempt, except I joined C0 to each member, i.e. C0=C1, C0=C2, C0=C3.  I've now tried as your above as well, however the query still hadnt returned any data at all after 5 minutes when I stopped it.  I even made sure all 4 columns are indexed with the same result.

Comment: I added another option with a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using EXISTS as well. Demo - http://rextester.com/SRSIH80664

```
SELECT T1.CourseChair
FROM   Table1 as T1  
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 as T2 WHERE T1.CourseChair = T2.Member1 AND T2.Member1 IS NOT NULL)
AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 as T3 WHERE T1.CourseChair = T3.Member2 AND T3.Member2 IS NOT NULL)
AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 as T4 WHERE T1.CourseChair = T4.Member3 AND T4.Member3 IS NOT NULL);
```